# Looking for a library/framework to stream live video from OS X to Wowza server (RTMP)

Tags: macos, rtmp, wowza

I already know I can stream a video file via FFMPEG to my wowza server but what I need to be able to do is stream live video (For example from the built in webcam or other attached cameras) to the server.

One method I considered was saving the video to short ~10sec files and then using FFMPEG to stream those up to the wowza server but I face 2 issues with that. First, how can I insure there will be no breaks in the feed when I switch to the next video clip to stream. Two, how do I set it up to record in 10 second chunks without missing anything in between.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jo, I am looking for the same development. I have wowza streaming engine and iOS Media lib, do not know how to stream video frames to wowza from media lib iOS project for live streaming. Can you share sample code please?

Comment: Stella, I never got it figured out. My company bought some iOS library (can't remember the name) to handle it and then shortly afterwards dropped the project and it wasn't finished. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for commercial solutions you might try:
http://www.adobe.com/de/products/flash-media-encoder.html

If you're looking to code something on your own you should search for "RTMP Client library",
you can find (semi) commercial ones:
http://www.smaxe.com/juvclient.jsf
or fully free ones like the RTMPClient.java.
There are also implementations of audio codecs that can be found in the Net. However I don't know any video captcha code that is Open for OSX. You would need to code something here on your own.

Comment: I will look into using Adobe's but I don't think that will work for this project. Also I need a way to publish the RTMP stream to a server not just a client. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: If you are looking for a simple Java Client that can connect via RTMP you can also use http://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/java/client/trunk/src/org/red5/client/net/rtmp/RTMPClient.java

Comment: Hi Seba, I am looking for the same development. I have wowza streaming engine and iOS Media lib, do not know how to stream video frames to wowza from media lib iOS project for live streaming. Can you share sample code please?

Comment: You could use `ffmpeg` for video capture. Also, captcha is an entirely distinct technology.

Answer (score 1):

The best tool on OS X for streaming from your Desktop is [CamTwistStudio](http://camtwiststudio.com/) (formerly CamTwist). CamTwistStudio is used for [NASA's SpaceVidcast](http://www.spacevidcast.com/) service.

Check this extensive tutorial [Free Live Video Streaming with HTTP Live Streaming, uStream, justin.tv, ffmpeg, vlc, x264, Wowza, CamTwist and Flash Media Encoder in a GNU Linux environment and Mac OS-X](http://blog.kyri0s.org/post/1406637341/free-live-video-streaming-with-http-live-streaming) for a full description of how you can stream from OS X to the Internet.

A more powerful commercial product is [Wirecast](http://www.telestream.net/wirecast/overview.htm). Check this article for information on the product:
http://www.tuaw.com/2012/02/26/wirecast-pro-for-mac-4-1-3-a-close-look-at-a-powerful-webcastin/